# TypeError: fetch failed when deploying to Vercel (Next.js)

Tags: next.js, fetch-api, vercel

I'm building a website using `next.js` which uses `Route Handlers`. When I run the `npm run build` command it works perfectly fine, but when I deploy to Vercel it shows this error:
`TypeError: fetch failed at Object.fetch (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:11457:11) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) { cause: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) at TCPConnectWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) { errno: -111, code: 'ECONNREFUSED', syscall: 'connect', address: '127.0.0.1', port: 3000 } }`
`Error: Command "npm run build" exited with 1`
Can someone tell me where the issue is? There no errors in the browser console, nor in the build command. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Search } from '@/components'

async function getJobs() {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/jobs');
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error("Couldn't fetch")
  }
  const data = await res.json();
  return data;
}

export default async function Home() {
  const jobs = await getJobs();

  return (
    <main className='px-6 md:px-8'>
      <Search />
      <pre>{ JSON.stringify(jobs, null, 2)}</pre>
      <span>{new Date().getTime()}</span>
    </main> 
  )
}

export const revalidate = 900;
```

Any help is appreciated. If you need more information about this problem, feel free to ask. Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to request an API in the api folder of your project? Because if so you should call `fetch("/api/jobs")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve that, add a .env file at the project root with an enviroment variable receiveing the 'http://localhost:3000' value, then import to your fetch url by using `${process.env.NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE}/api/jobs`. then go to your dashboard in vercel and set the value of NAME_OF_YOUR_ENV_VARIABLE as the base url of the deploy gave by vercel.

Comment: This wont work for preview deployments. It would be better to use the VERCEL_URL environment variable. I've ran into issues with this on pages that just use tags for cache policy.

Answer (score 2):

in `next.config.js` write `env:{}`
https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/next-config-js/env
for exp.

```
env: { API_URL: "https://yours-project.vercel.app"} and use this API_URL in fetch
const apiUrl = process.env.API_URL;
const res = await fetch(`${apiUrl}/api/jobs`, {
cache: "no-store",
});
```

it helped me.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is sweet, sweet relief after 2+ hours of debugging

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `fetch` works differently in each and every "Runtime".
So, it might help to change the runtime.

[Here's the link to Vercel's docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/route-segment-config)

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your .env variable with prefix `NEXT_PUBLIC` like for example:

`NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL=http://localhost:3000`

You got errors in production mode because if you directly set it as `API_URL=http://localhost:3000`, Next.js assumes that this is a secret variable therefore it can't make a request from client-side.